# How should a load be connected in a configuration of a MPPT solar charger and a LiPo battery?

Tags: battery-charging, mppt, solar-charge-controller

I am designing a circuit for MPPT solar charger [SPV1040](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/spv1040.pdf) which could charge a single-cell LiPo battery. I am using [AN3319](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00292052.pdf) and [AN4050](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00048561.pdf) application notes for reference.

I also want to connect a load along with the solar charger and the battery such that the load is powered 24/7 even when the charger is not supplying any charging current (the load is small enough that the daytime charging will replenish the charge consumed by the load during 24 hour period).

Do I need to design a further circuit or just putting the load in parallel to the battery would work too?

Comment: You can do it using Charging IC that ISOLATE battery from load during charging. I previously worked on bq24070 charging IC, it might help you in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the load in parallel with the battery.